# Developing a simple Internet Explorer Extension

Tags: internet-explorer, browser-extension

I am trying to develop a simple Internet Explorer Extension where a button is added to the toolbar and clicking the button opens a specific url. Thats it. This should be pretty simple Extension. Can someone please guide me in the right direction. Thanks a bunch.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this with a simple registry key. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa753588.aspx